# Is it possible to have automated joomla installation in whm

Tags: joomla

I have VPS with cpanel WHM . i want to know is there any plugin addon so that on account i can automatically install joomla with simple clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fantastico](https://netenberg.com/fantastico.php) will automate Joomla installs (and many other things), but isn't free.

Comment: Any other free option , avaialbe , may be some shell script

Comment: Not that I am aware of, no.